# Caldera Forms + CiviCRM + Payment Processors

Tags: wordpress, caldera-forms

Hi I'm new with WP + CiviCRM and I would like to integrate WP forms + Civi + payment processors, I see that Caldera was the option, but now that it will no longer be available,
do I have to wait for Ninja Forms? I have tried Caldera but it doesn't let me integrate any payment gateway, it seems that they are independent addons that are no longer available for new users. Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cesar, we have been using Caldera + [PaypalPro addon](https://calderaforms.com/downloads/paypal-pro/) + Civicrm for a long while and it has been very solid so I am sorry to see it phased out. The new owners seem committed to work with Civicrm - see the update at the bottom of [this post](https://calderaforms.com/2021/09/conversion-tool-1-0-live-more-transition-updates/?utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=Conversion%20Tool%201%200%20is%20Live%21&utm_campaign=Caldera%20Forms%20Conversion%20Tool%20is%20Live%21). They have released a conversion tool and have a Civicrm addon in development, and expect to have it done by the end of 2021. So to answer your question, it does look like the future is with Ninja forms, but at the moment we are stuck with no alternatives for new WP users.

Comment: Ok thanks, it looks like I came at a good time, we will wait for Ninja's progress.